# SQL query selects all records of support tickets along with their files

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables inside the database, one of which is for support tickets, and the other table is for uploaded files for tickets, and my question is how can I select all the tickets and their uploaded files, even for Tickets that do not have a file.

My SQL query is as follows, but it show me tickets that have a file and does not display tickets that do not have a file.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.tblTickets.id, dbo.tblTickets.uid, 
    dbo.tblTicketReplys.tsenderusername, 
    dbo.tblTicketReplys.tBody, dbo.tblTicketReplys.tdate, 
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.[fileName], 
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.fileLink,
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.fileSize
FROM    
    dbo.tblTickets
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplys ON dbo.tblTickets.id = dbo.tblTicketReplys.tid 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments ON dbo.tblTicketReplys.id = dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.repID
WHERE
    (dbo.tblTickets.[uid] = @uid)
    AND (dbo.tblTicketReplys.tid = @tid)
ORDER BY 
    dbo.tblTickets.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT        
    dbo.tblTickets.id, dbo.tblTickets.uid, dbo.tblTicketReplys.tsenderusername, 
    dbo.tblTicketReplys.tBody, dbo.tblTicketReplys.tdate, dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.[fileName], 
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.fileLink,dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.fileSize
FROM    
    dbo.tblTickets
JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplys ON dbo.tblTickets.id = dbo.tblTicketReplys.tid 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments ON dbo.tblTicketReplys.id = dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.repID
where (dbo.tblTickets.[uid]=@uid)AND(dbo.tblTicketReplys.tid=@tid)
order by dbo.tblTickets.id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change JOIN to LEFT JOIN to tblTicketReplysAttachments's table:

```
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments ON dbo.tblTicketReplys.id = dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.repID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM dbo.tblTickets T1
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblTicketReplys T2 ON dbo.tblTickets.id = dbo.tblTicketReplys.tid
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments T3 ON dbo.tblTicketReplys.id = dbo.tblTicketReplysAttachments.repID
```

Only those tickets will get listed where `T1.id = T2.ti`d and `T2.id = T3.repID`
Unless `T2.tid = T2.id` you are not joining the 1st table to the 3rd table.

Coming to the main question of getting only tickets with attachments
If your T3(which holds data for attachments) only has those tickets where there are attachments, then because you are using INNER JOIN, you will only get tickets that have attachments. You can replace it with **LEFT JOIN** which will give you 
1. All rows from T1 
2. All rows that match the condition from T2 & T3